# Cocoa: Display HTML from string

Tags: html, cocoa, api

How can I display properly formatted text from an NSString, that just happens to be HTML.  The html is coming from the stack overflow API.

Comment: Make sure you don't parse SO's HTML with RegExes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [create a NSAttributedString from HTML](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html). You then draw it as you would draw any other NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 1):

If your tags are accurate and you are programming for OS X (or iPhone 4.0+), you can use NSAttributedString's [– initWithHTML:documentAttributes:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithHTML:documentAttributes:), and then draw that directly.

Unfortunately, the iPhone OS' UIKit does not contain NSAttributedString pre-4.0.  The current recommendation from the developer docs is to use a UIWebView, which sucks.  An alternative might be the [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) library, which contains [TTStyledText](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/TTStyledText.m) -- that looks like it might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a WebView, and tell the WebView's `mainFrame` to [load the HTML string](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebFrame/loadHTMLString:baseURL:).

If you meant to ask about Cocoa Touch, [UIWebView has an equivalent method for you](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:).